# Getting the type by address in WinDbg

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

Suppose I have an address of some object placed in unmanaged heap. How can I get the C++ type of the object in WinDbg?

Comment: I doubt you can get type of the memory block. You can coerce a memory block to what you think this memory contains with **dt** command, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't foolproof, but it often works.

1. Run `!heap -x ADDR`. This will provide the user pointer.
2. Run `dps USERPOINTER`. For a C++ object, this will usually give you a vtable symbol name.